# Turning a flat Python tuple into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, python-itertools

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```py
(
    ('Category 1', 40),
    ('Category 1 | Sub-Category 1', 20),
    ('Category 1 | Sub-Category 2', 20),
    ('Category 1 | Sub-Category 2 | Sub-Sub-Category 1', 5),
    ('Category 1 | Sub-Category 2 | Sub-Sub-Category 2', 15),
    ('Category 2', 20),
    ('Category 2 | Sub-Category 1', 15),
    ('Category 2 | Sub-Category 2', 5)
)
```

I would like to turn it into a dictionary that looks like this:

```py
{
    'Category 1': {
        'count': 40,
        'children': {
            'Sub-Category 1': {'count': 20, 'children': []},
            'Sub-Category 2': {
                'count': 20,
                'children': {
                    'Sub-Sub-Category 1': {'count': 5, 'children': []},
                    'Sub-Sub-Category 2': {'count': 15, 'children': []}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'Category 2': {
        'count': 20,
        'children': {
            'Sub-Category 1': {'count': 15, 'children': []},
            'Sub-Category 2': {'count': 5, 'children': []},
        }
    }
}
```

There are an arbitrary number of sub-categories. I'm having a tough time thinking of a Pythonic way of doing this. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: In case anyone else runs into this kind of problem and wants a solution, here's what I (finally) came up with. I would post as an answer, but can't, due to the question being closed (sigh).

```py
from itertools import groupby

def categoriesdict(value, depth=0):
    categories = {}
    for name, children in groupby(value, lambda c: c[0].split(' | ')[depth]):
        # assumes that the first child is the group info
        categories[name] = {
            'count': children.next()[1],
            'children': categoriesdict(children, depth + 1)
        }
    return categories
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: But, I'll make a suggestion: recursion.

Comment: Since there are an arbitrary number of sub-categories I know that recursion will most likely be part of the solution. My attempts so far haven't worked and aren't complete. I will post my attempts in a bit, I apologize for not posting them intially, but was the downvote really necessary?

Comment: Yes. At present this is just a beg for code.

Comment: My first comment is not my original creation. It is one of the stated criteria for closing a question. Simple begging for code without posting your own attempts is not welcome here.

Comment: Sigh. I just figured out a solution anyway (see my edit). Enough understanding for you?

Answer (score 2):

For each 2-tuple, split the first tuple `[el.strip() for el in path.split('|')]`, then follow that path creating dictionaries and sub-dictionaries.

<strike>I'll edit in some code within a few minutes.</strike>

```
d = {'count': 0, 'children': {}}
for (path, count) in els:
    path = [el.strip() for el in path.split('|')]
    here = d
    for el in path:
        print(el)
        if el not in here['children']:
            here['children'][el] = {'count': 0, 'children': {}}
        here = here['children'][el]
    here['count'] = count
```